# '<' is misleading when using ordered factors

Tags: r

While trying out a few things with ordered factors, I observe that on giving ordered=TRUE, the output is printed out in the same order as the levels mentioned in your command. See below.

```
> data = c("yes","yes","no","maybe","maybe","maybe")
> fac = factor(data,levels=c("yes","no","maybe"),ordered = T)
> table(fac)
fac
  yes    no maybe 
    2     1     3 
> fac = factor(data,levels=c("no","yes","maybe"),ordered = T)
> table(fac)
fac
   no   yes maybe 
    1     2     3 
> fac = factor(data,levels=c("maybe","yes","no"),ordered = T)
> table(fac)
fac
maybe   yes    no 
    3     2     1
```

I have two questions here
1. So, the word ordered refers to just ordering on the basis of levels given? How then do I print out in terms of ascending order of count, ie "no" followed by "yes" followed by "maybe"

2. If the count is not taken into consideration, what does the symbol '<' signify? It gives out the false impression that the count of no < maybe < yes which is not true.

   > fac = factor(data,levels=c("no","maybe","yes"),ordered = T)
   >
   > fac
   >   [1] yes   yes   no    maybe maybe maybe
   >       Levels: no < maybe < yes
3. ordered=T needs levels, (because it basically orders on the basis of levels). Don't you think it should throw an error when we try to use ordered=T without specifying levels? Are we just going ahead with the assumption that the default levels is the alphabetical ordering of levels?

Comment: In response to your first question, you can use `sort` on the table

Comment: Thanks @RichardScriven, was able to do using sort(table(fac)). But isn't no < maybe < yes when you specify levels=c("no","maybe","yes") slightly misleading?

Comment: I don't think it is misleading because that's the way you've set up the ordering of the levels.  Notice that the ordering is always the same as the way you enter them in the `levels` argument.  Perhaps I'm not fully understanding the question though

Comment: The settings of `ordered=F/T` is the difference between defining a categorical random variable or an ordinal random variable. It has more to do with how you wish to interpret the different levels. It has nothing do to with the number of observations for a each level. Some statistical methods treat categorical and ordinal variables differently.

Comment: @RichardScriven, right. My bad! Just that when I see the '<', I immediately get a 'less than' feeling, like they're sorted and printed on the basis of ascending order.